# RxAndroid + Retrofit 2, getting a list of books

Tags: retrofit2, rx-android

So, let's say I need to get a list of favorite books for an Android app.

I have the list of ids, but I can only get one book at a time, so, I don't really have a `bookAPI.getFavoriteBooks(listOfFavoriteIds)` method call (the server doesn't have an endpoint for that), but instead I'd have to call `bookAPI.getBook(id)` for each `id` in the list to get all the favorite books, and after I get them I should return a list with the results.

The answers I've found so far assume that there's a method `Observable<List<Book>> getFavoriteBooks(List<Integer> ids)`I could call, but in this case I don't have that.

Is there a way of solving this question using RxAndroid and Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say from your question if this fits your needs, but you could try:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOfIds)
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<Book>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Book> apply(Integer integer)
                                                     throws Exception {
                    return bookApi.getBook(id);
                }
            })
            .toList()
```

Let me explain what's happening here. `fromIterable` creates an observable that emits each element in the iterable as an event. In this case it will emit each book id.

You then flat map said observable to your api observable. So in this case you're mapping each emitted Id to an observable that emits each book from the api.

Finally, you collect all the emitted books as a list. Once you subscribe to this stream it will have a list as a single event:

```
// whatever way you get the above stream
.subscribe(new Consumer<List<Book>>() {
         @Override
         public void accept(List<Book> result) throws Exception {
            // do whatever you want with result
         }
  });
```

Just make sure to use the right schedulers for your use case.

*(Careful because this subscribe call doesn't handle errors, but I guess you can figure that out pretty easily)*

Comment: Life saver. It worked, thanks! Even though I was reading more about functional java, I thought it was easier to just map getBook() over the list of integers; something like map(getBook, ids) and work from there, but your answer appeared before testing my idea (which by reading this seems too simplistic), and it works, so, thanks again!